# Determine if a property is a backref in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following relationship set up in a model:

```
role_profiles = Table('roleprofile', Base.metadata,
                  Column('role_id', Integer, ForeignKey('role.id')),
                  Column('profile_id', Integer, ForeignKey('profile.id'))
                  )

class profile(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'profile'

    # Columns...

    roles = relationship('role', secondary=role_profiles, backref='profiles')


class role(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'role'

    # Columns...
```

So as I now understand that it works is that the roles property on the profile object will contain a list of role classes (which it does).

What I want to do is to serialize for each property of the model class generically. It works fine for the top class profile and I determine that there is a list of `roles` that I should recurse into:

```
# I need a statement here to check if the field.value is a backref
#if field.value is backref:
#    continue

if isinstance(field.value, list):
    # Get the json for the list
    value = serialize.serialize_to_json(field.value)
else:
    # Get the json for the value
    value = cls._serialize(field.value)
```

The problem is that the `backref` of the relationship adds a pointer back to the profile. The same profile is then serialized and it recurse the roles over and over again until `stack overflow`.

Is there a way to determine that the property is a `backref` added by the `relationship`?

**Update**

Maybe I should add that it works fine in this case if I remove the `backref` since I don't need it but I would like to keep it in.

**Update**

As a temporary fix I added a class property to my base class:

```
class BaseModelMixin(object):
    """Base mixin for models using stamped data"""

    __backref__ = None
```

and add it like this:

```
class role(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'role'
    __backref__ = ('profiles', )

    # Columns...
```

and use it like this in my recursion:

```
if self.__backref__ and property_name in self.__backref__:
    continue
```

If there is a better way please let me know because this doesn't look optimal.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `__relationships__` in your class `BaseModelMixin` as a `@property`, which has a list of all relationships name which are not as a backref name in a model.

```
class BaseModelMixin(object):
"""Base mixin for models using stamped data"""

    @property
    def __relationships__(self):  
        """
        Return a list of relationships name which are not as a backref
        name in model    
        """
        back_ref_relationships = list()
        items = self.__mapper__.relationships.items()
        for (key, value) in items:
            if isinstance(value.backref, tuple):
                back_ref_relationships.append(key)
        return back_ref_relationships
```

As you have two class `profile` and `role`, so

```
>>> p = profile()
>>> p.__relationships__
    # ['roles']

>>> r = role()
>>> r.__relationships__
   # []
```

Comment: Great Answer! sqlalchemy should have made it easier to identify backrefs and relationships.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is the best practice, but this code works for me. It returns True if the attribute is a reference, False if a regular column type.

```
def is_relation(orm_object, attr_name):
    return hasattr(getattr(orm_object.__class__, attr_name).property, 'mapper')
```

Answer (score 2):

have a look at [`inspect`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/inspection.html)

e.g.

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect
mapper = inspect(MyModelClass)
# dir(mapper)
# mapper.relationships.keys()
```

Comment: Will do. I'll be back... Thanks

Comment: Be careful you don't clash with Python's builtin `inspect`